# Explicit computation of the cotangent complex in a non-lci case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cotangent-complex

Is there an example of a non-lci morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ for which the entire cotangent complex (or just Andre-Quillen cohomology) can be explicitly computed? I believe it is a theorem of Avramov that in the non-lci case the cohomology is nonzero in every degree $\geq 1.$ There are explicit formulas (Lichtenbaum-Schlessinger) for the cohomologies in degree $0,1,2$; I don't know any example computations beyond degree $2$.

Comment: See this question : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/143806/computing-cotangent-complex.

Comment: That is not exactly true. See Corollary 3 in [http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404997001035] for a characterization of vanishing in _all_ degrees $\geq 3$. From it, its not difficult to see an example of a non-complete intersection $A \to A/(x)$ such that cohomology vanishes in degrees $\geq 3$.